# Listview items text is not showing complete

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to create an activity for Admin to approve some Posts(by user) to publish, so I'm using Listview where all posts will be checked/unchecked. **Now the issue is that some posts have large text and this big text is not showing properly in listview row.**
I'm new to software development I searched all solutions, one is to use custom listview but I'm not getting it.

here are my files:

approvepost.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        tools:context=".ApprovePost"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
    
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the main class...
ApprovePost.java

````
    package com.ahmed.signup;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class ApprovePost extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static final String TAG = "ListView";
        private ListView listView;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.approvepost);
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            // CHOICE_MODE_NONE: (Default)
            // (listView.setItemChecked(..) doest not work with CHOICE_MODE_NONE).
            // CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE:
            // CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE:
            // CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL:
           listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick: " +position);
                    CheckedTextView v = (CheckedTextView) view;
                    boolean currentCheck = v.isChecked();
                    ApprovePostDto user = (ApprovePostDto) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    user.setActive(!currentCheck);
                }
            });
    
            this.initListViewData();
        }
    
        private void initListViewData()  {
            ApprovePostDto user1 = new ApprovePostDto("Ali", "I would like to set up a meeting to give an overview of Foxit and demo the features important to your workflows.");
            ApprovePostDto user2 = new ApprovePostDto("Haider", "See the data in your Google Account and choose what activity is saved to personalize your Google experience");
            ApprovePostDto user3 = new ApprovePostDto("Usman", "Your account storage is shared across Google services, like Gmail and Photos");
    
            ApprovePostDto[] users = new ApprovePostDto[]{user1,user2, user3};
            ArrayAdapter<ApprovePostDto> arrayAdapter
                    = new ArrayAdapter<ApprovePostDto>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked , users);
    
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    
            ProgressDialog progress;
    
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.setTitle("Please Wait!!");
            progress.setMessage("Wait!!");
            progress.setCancelable(true);
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    
            for(int i=0;i< users.length; i++ )  {
                listView.setItemChecked(i,users[i].isActive());
    
                progress.show();
    
            }
        }
    }
     ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use this in initListViewData method

```
ArrayAdapter<ApprovePostDto> arrayAdapter
                    = new ArrayAdapter<ApprovePostDto>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , users);
```

instead

```
ArrayAdapter<ApprovePostDto> arrayAdapter
                    = new ArrayAdapter<ApprovePostDto>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked , users);
```

**2nd Suggestion**

Create new layout have the below code in it. Refer this layout in your adapter that would work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"/>
```

Comment: Actually I want Checkbox with all row list item to check/uncheck, so that's why I'm using 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked

Comment: Thankyou @learner. I tried a custom layout and that is working fine

Comment: @ahmednawazCS Mark my answer as accepted. If my solution helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If the layout of your list items (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked`) does not work very well for large texts you can always create your own layout.

`TextView` and `CheckedTextView` have some attributes that will help:

```
android:lines="2" // use more lines
android:ellipsize="marquee" // scroll your text horizontally
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" // makes your text smaller/larger depending on available space
app:autoSizeMinTextSize="11sp"
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="14sp"
```

PS: Set your `ListView` width and height to `match_parent`